# load file only with extension and black list of executable file on SaveFileDialog.Filter

Tags: winforms

how can I define SaveFileDialog.Filter to load files only with an extension
,ex:
file1.xml
file3.txt
file3

file3 will Drop

I accidentally try that "all file|*.?*" and succeed but still now can't figure out the syntax. Any way, How can I add to this filter **a black list of executable file**, for say .bat .exe

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/921975/1298333) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible to use regular expressions in `SaveFileDialog`.
But you can try to set `"Files with extension|*.?*"` to the `Filter` property. Looks like it works.

Comment: Yeah you right. I accidentally try that and succeed but still now can't figure out the syntax "*.?*" . Any way, how can i add to this filter a black list of executable file, for say .bat .exe

Comment: `"?"` - means "some symbol". For example if you write `*.???` then only files with extension length equal to 3 like ".bat" or ".txt" will be shown and for example ".cs" will be hidden.