# C# OpenFileDialog filter - allow all extensions except one

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, file-extension, openfiledialog

How do I filter files with a certain file extension from a list of files displaying in OpenFileDialog in C# Windows forms application?

I want the user to select a file, but with one rule: it mustn't be an `.exe` file. While I know that I can check the file name after the user selects it and display an error if it ends with `.exe`, it will display .exe files in the selection, which I don't want.

I know that user can select any file he wants if they type the name of the file in the input box in the OpenFileDialog, but I got that covered in a different way. I just don't want `.exe` files visible in the selection, since the user won't be allowed to select them anyway.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921937/excluding-file-extensions-from-open-file-dialog-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for, but I couldn't find it on my own.